# How can I solve the error: File `styles/thesis.sty' not found. ^^M

Tags: errors

can anyone please help.I have tex-studio and tex live, i have tried a couple of stuff i saw for similar problems to no avail. I am running on Ubuntu 20.04.

below is what I am getting:

```
 LaTeX Error: File `styles/thesis.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 
         
l.9 ^^M
       
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)

 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 226 strings out of 481239
 2576 string characters out of 5920377
 236562 words of memory out of 5000000
 15583 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 532638 words of font info for 25 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 23i,0n,21p,271b,36s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: do you have a file called thesis.sty ?

Comment: your document does `\usepackage{styles/thesis}` so it assumes there is a file of that name. there is no standard file of that name, if you copied this from somewhere you need to copy the whole document not just the main file, so that files it inputs are on your local system.